# Singularity of symmetric block matrix with singular diagonal blocks

Tags: reference-request, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrix-inverse, block-matrices

One can show that the following statement holds:

> Given symmetric matrix $A \in \Re^{n \times n}$ and tall matrix $B \in \Re^{n \times p}$ with full column rank,
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ B^T & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> is invertible if and only if $C^TAC$ is invertible and $C  \in \Re^{n \times (n-p)}$ is a full column rank matrix with $C^TB = 0$.

This is a simple problem, so there might be a text that states this. Can you give me a reference that explicitly states this? I need to find it because I want to use the statement above in a paper and cite a reference instead of providing the proof.

Comment: Section 4 of this:
http://msvlab.hre.ntou.edu.tw/grades/now/inte/Inverse%20&%20Border/border-LuTT.pdf
seems to be related

Comment: Why not answer your own question and provide your own proof, and then cite your MathOverflow answer in your paper?